# Value at $0$ of solution to ODE, given asymptotic behaviour

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R\qquad f'(x) =  f(x)^2 -x^2. $$
[image]

Every solution that crosses the line $y=x$ where $x>0$ is asymptotic to $y=-x$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$. The other solutions with $f(0)>0$ are above the former and their limit at $+\infty$ is $+\infty$.

I then expect there to be a solution $g$ which is asymptotic to $y=x$ as $x$ approaches $+\infty$. What I'd like to know is $g(0)$ and how to get the result. Well, an explicit expression for $g$ would be better, but I doubt there is one.

The only thing I was I able to do so far was making GeoGebra plot some (approximated) solutions, as you can see from the picture.

Comment: Consider the equation satisfied by $u(x) = f(x) - x$, i.e. $u'(x) = u^2(x) + 2xu(x) - 1$.  According to Mathematica, the general solution may be found in terms of modified Bessel functions. Find the solution that goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ and evaluate it at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

After the substitution $f(x)=-u'(x)/u(x),$ you get the linear differential equation $u''(x)=x^2u(x)$. This is essentially (i.e. up to scaling) Weber's equation, the solutions are parabolic cylinder functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function).
The one you're interested in (with the correct asympotic behavior) would be $u(x)=D_{-1/2}(x\sqrt{2}).$ So your $g(0)$ would be
$$g(0)=-\sqrt{2}\,\frac{D'_{-1/2}(0)}{D_{-1/2}(0)}=\sqrt{2}\,\frac{D_{1/2}(0)}{D_{-1/2}(0)}$$ due to known expressions for the derivatives of such functions. So you have to ask Wolfram Alpha:
sqrt(2)* ParabolicCylinderD[0.5,0]/ParabolicCylinderD[-0.5,0]
The answer is $0.675978240067284728995447684670805748287283454915405951976\ldots,$ that seems to be consistent with your picture.
As @Hans Engler pointed out, the solution can also be expressed through modified Bessel functions ($K_{1/4}$, to be more precise), but that wouldn't give an advantage, here.